# Socket connection not getting established when using https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to make a socket connection with the react frontend. When I do the connection with http API, it works perfectly fine, but when I'm trying to connect the same with https server, I get this error of connection failed.

Here's my react code to connect:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";


const CONNECTION_PORT = 'https://socket.abcd.com/api'         // (I did reverse proxy in nginx for /api endpoint) which is not connecting. I also have SSL certificate purchased for this API. Whereas,

const CONNECTION_PORT = 'http://localhost:5000'.    // this works perfectly fine.

useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(CONNECTION_PORT, {
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });
  });
```

Do anyone faced the same issue ? Please let me know what can be the fix for this.

Comment: it completey depends of the way you defined the proxy (nginx)

Answer (score 0):

it completely depends of the way you defined the proxy (nginx)

did you follow theses advices ?

https://socket.io/docs/v3/reverse-proxy/#NginX

Content of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I replace it with this or add this content in the file since I already have some default configuration in it ??

Comment: you'll need to adapt it to your domain / port at the very least